# How to insert code output in jupyter notebook markdown cell?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I have a markdown cell with text, and I want it to include some output from the code. For example, I have a variable `a` in Python that equals to 10, and I want that a markdown cell print something like this:

> We have the variable a=10...

without me specifically writing down 10

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have the jupyter notebook extensions installed. There is an extension called [`Python Markdown`](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tree/master/src/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/nbextensions/python-markdown) which allows you to do what you want.

In your case you wrap your variable `a` with curly brackets `{{a}}`. This will lead to

[image]

The code in the markdown cell resulting in "We have tha variable a=10" is accordingly:

```
We have the variable a={{a}}.
```